# using twigs functions (escaping) in action

Tags: symfony, twig

I was wondering if I can somehow access twig in action to use it's escaping function? I need this because I am converting text with markdown and will need to show it raw in templates, but want to escape it before I save it.

Can I access twig service somehow and what function would I call?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea to modify user input before persisting it. You should persist it as is and transform on output. If you are concerned about the performance of this approach, caching is the answer.

The reason for this is that if you have a bug in your transormation logic or decide later to change it, you'll be in a trouble if you persist the transformed input.

BTW, take a look at a [markdown bundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMarkdownBundle).

Comment: Thanks for advice. Can you give me an example of how I would implement caching in this scenario? Would I basically have a key value store? What do you use? If I use caching I still would need to access twig's escaping functions right? Any way I could do that? Or should I just use htmlspecialchars?

Comment: True, with two exceptions: sanitize and normalize user input before persisting, transform on output.